# How to make \underset and \stackrel distances equal?

Tags: mathtools

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$[ \underset{\scriptscriptstyle [[[[]]]]}
  {\stackrel{\mathclap{\scriptscriptstyle [[[[]]]]}}{[[[[]]]]}} ]$ \\
\end{document}
```

It renders as such:

[image]

The distance between the underscript and the main text is larger than the distance between the upperscript and the main text. How can I make them equal?

Comment: Side comment: nesting `\underset` with `\stackrel` will 1) make always a Rel atom whether you want it or not, and 2) give possibly unexpected results if you use this combination for single letters. It would be better to nest `\overset` with `\underset`, or with a recent `amsmath` you could simply use `\overunderset`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem can be illustrated by primitive construct:

```
$[\mathop{[[[[]]]]}\limits^{[[[[]]]]}_{[[[[]]]]}]$
```

Indeeed, the above kern is smaller than the bellow kern. The appendix G of The TeXbook, paragraph 13a, says that the above kern is max(xi9, xi11-dp) and below kern is max (xi10, xi12-ht). The values from Computer Modern are:

```
xi9 = \fontdimen9\textfont3     = 1.11111pt
xi10 = \fontdimen10\textfont3   = 1.66666pt
xi11 = \fontdimen11\textfont3   = 1.99998pt
xi12 = \fontdimen12\textfont3   = 6.0pt
dp = \dp\hbox{$\scriptstyle[]$} = 1.75pt
ht = \ht\hbox{$\scriptstyle[]$} = 5.25pt
```

We can see that the above maximum is xi9 and below maximum is xi10. So, we have kern above 1.11111pt and kern below 1.66666pt.

You can set better kern above by

```
\fontdimen9\textfont3=1.666666pt
```

Then you have the same kern above and below. Tested by `pdftex document`.

If we are using `luatex`, then setting the `\fontdimen` is irrelevant and we must to use LuaTeX primitive instead:

```
\Umathlimitabovevgap\textstyle=1.6666666pt
```

Tested by `luatex document` or `optex document`.

I tested the Unicode-math of LatinModern font too and I have found that the bug from Computer Modern is corrected here, the kern above and below are set uniformly to 1.666666pt. So, you can use Unicode-math Latin Modern to solve your problem.